# Should I lower my price for having no reputation?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, client-relations

First of all, I'm 16, and I've been using Adobe applications for 6 years. Since 2014, I've been "working" as a freelancer.
When it comes to pricing, I have a lot of problems:

- I haven't developed a portfolio yet
- My age doesn't help
- I'm too kind

Recently I made a logo and a badge for 13$. By now, I'm developing a book cover for 10$.

I consider theses prices to be really low, sorry if you don't agree

Why? Because when I try to charge my real price, people refuse to pay.

- " Too young and too high "
- " I know a guy that does it for less "
- " I can only pay X$ " (this one refers to kindness)"

What should I do?

Comment: In order to make *more* money you **must** be willing to say "no" to $10 projects. Relevant answer: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/25713/3270

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hum. Let me adress ths points, but I will add the real question here.

- Is your work outstanding? Really good? Average? So - so?

The rest of the points depends on that question.

> My age doesn't help

I really do not care about this, but the point related with age is experience;  if your proposal really solves a comunication problem, a visual identity problem or just is a nice work.

Working for some years with an aplication does not make you a designer. I will post a rude example but the case could be similar. Working with wrenches and screwdriver does not make one an automobile designer. The program is just a tool.

> I'm too kind

Nop, probably you are insecure, and probably you need more experience, and knowing the work you do gives real added value to the client.

> I haven't developed a portfolio yet.

This is the first step. Do this and confront it with people and see if it has added value.

I do not really know if your prices are good or not, because I have not viewed your work.

Take a look at this: [Why is it that people are so surprised that graphics design can be hard?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/70510/why-is-it-that-people-are-so-surprised-that-graphics-design-can-be-hard)

I have this graph:

Where the income is given by 2 variables.

The quality of your work, and the type of client you have.

The type of client is probably limited by your age right now, because probably a medium sized company will not hire someone your age. But again, the most important aspect is talent and problem solving work.

[image]

Comment: Perfect answer. I'm gonna improve immediately on the points you marked. Thank you!

Comment: Don't forget the market conditions. What you may get for your work in New York will not be the same in a small town in a minor market area.