# How to build an online portfolio?

Tags: website-design, designers, information-graphics, portfolio

I want to build a personal portfolio so my questions related are as follows:

1. What should I include in the portfolio apart from Home, About, Work, Contact?
2. I have never worked on any real life examples so what to display in the work/portfolio page?
3. What kind of design samples do I need to include? Ex: Website, Logo, Banner etc

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/53813/whose-persona-should-i-consider-while-designing-my-portfolio

Comment: I think [my splash page](http://zachsaucier.com/) is a good example for someone starting out. It's **short**, focused, and shows highlights *only*. No fluff, people don't care to know all about you, just get an impression of what you can do

Answer (score 3):

> What should I include in the portfolio apart from Home, About, Work, Contact?

That is not a portafolio. That is the CV. Be carefull on publishing adresses on a web page if it is not a business adress.

> I have never worked on any real life examples so what to display in the work/portfolio page?

Display what you have done, you can not show what you have not done... I know, lame answer, but a profund one.

> What kind of design samples do I need to include? Ex: Website, Logo, Banner etc.

Ok I am going more serious this time. Take a look at this question: [Whose persona should I consider while designing my portfolio?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/53813/whose-persona-should-i-consider-while-designing-my-portfolio)

You are a seller of your work.

- What do you want to sell?
- What product you have?
- What product you do not have but want/plann to produce and sell?

I personally do not give a hoot :o) if a great image, logo, web template is not used by a real business. If it is good it is good. So my answer is: prepare a good work.

Take a look at this few seconds of this video: https://youtu.be/H7eWZFgo2xI?t=2m22s