# The Client's Customer Isn't the End-User. How Do I Pitch My Design Idea to the Client?

Tags: logo, client-relations

I was taught to always focus the design on the end-user, which is the client's customer, because it's easier to pitch an idea when it's about the customer.

However, this one client wants me to design a logo and their brand material for their personal satisfaction, not their customer's. And they told me that a lot of their customers never notice or seem to care about their visual identity because of the industry they are in and that they are also still learning about their customers.

So my question is how should I pitch my design idea to the client when the customer isn't the end-user of the design?

Comment: What about your client's views doesn't match the needs of the consumers? This question would be a lot better with an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your client is your client.

Normally the end user is not at our grasp. You can design a label for a jelly to be sold on a supermarket, but first it needs to be approved by the jelly company.

Take a look at this: [Whose persona should I consider while designing my portfolio?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/53813/whose-persona-should-i-consider-while-designing-my-portfolio/53850#53850)

Make it clear that the design is not really optimized for the real purpose and as a consultant you do not really recommend the result. And you will be ready when they need the redesign.

One side note, if the recommended design ideas are really awesome, it is more likely to be approved.

Comment: I don't think planning on redesigning later is a very good option... I agree with your main point that in the end it is the clients decision and that we as designers work for them, but I think the way you approach that is not very helpful for the client and disregards the skill that designers have which is (*should*) be part of the reason why they're hired in the first place

Comment: Yea but if a client wants to pay for a designer to make a crappy design there are two options. 1) Regret the project for the sake of mankind, or 2) Take the money, be a computer monkey for a week and just move foward... Just do not use that on your portafolio.

Comment: I really, really like this change in attitude. It's not about resenting the client, but looking at them as users of their own project — they can turn into the end-user of their own project. And for me that's really interesting because now I know how to handle that and avoid that misunderstanding in the future. Thanks Rafael.